# Fedora 24 KDE - no persistent volume settings per application

Tags: fedora, audio, kde, pulseaudio, volume

I use Fedora 24 KDE, fully updated, with "Audio Volume - System Settings Module".

I want to be able to change the volume of **programs** (not individual streams) **persistenly** (surviving program or OS restart), regardless of whether the programs are currently playing a sound or not.

Right now the "applications" tab only lets me modify currently playing streams.

So now:

- I can't mute applications that aren't currently play a sound;
- I can't adjust Firefox's volume, only individual streams (e.g. different YouTube videos).

[image: Audio Volume - System Settings Module]

Comment: Will anyone help me? This is getting super annoying. When I open a new YT video, the volume in "Applications" **randomly** changes from 100 to 73 or 87 or whatever. I **always** have to adjust it to 100%. Also, I **don't** want "per channel", but per application settings. Real application settings where Firefox = 1 applcation, not 10.